# Install Qubes Os R4.1.2 on MacbookPro 2019 (i9) problem : BCMDHD_ExitBootService

Tags: macintosh, qubes

I`m trying to install (Dualboot) Qubes on my MacbookPro 2019 i9 (with T2 Security Chip)

This is what I have done so far:

I downloaded the ISO file, verified it and flashed it to an USB stick. After flashing I re-verified the installer medium.

I disabled all Security setting of the T2 chip in Startup Security Utility. (Secure Boot - No Security & Allowed Boot Media - Allow booting from external or removable media)

Booted into the Startup Manager and chose EFI boot.

Chose the option: Install Qubes OS R4.1.2 (I also tried all other available options with the same result)

Then I get the following:

BCMDHD_ExitBootService: ENTER
dhd_os_wifi_platform_set_power: Setting wl_reg_on to 0 succeeded
dhd_os_wifi_platform_set_power: Setting wl_reg_on to 1 succeeded

I have waited for around 1 hour and noting else happens.
Pressing ENTER shows no result either.

I have tried the same with an Ubuntu 22.04.2 Installer, then it shows the same lines but switches to the installer window after a few seconds (mouse and keyboard don`t work though)

Any suggestions how I could make this work?